# JQuery code works in console but not in script tag or external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an Etch-A-Sketch using a grid of boxes created from div elements, but the code handling the highlighting of the boxes (mouseenter method) is not working. However, it works when the code is placed in the console, so I am confused as to what is causing the problem.

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function() {

        $('#container').empty();                                                    
        var row = prompt("How many rows are desired?");
        var col = prompt("How many columns are desired?");

        for (var j=0; j<=row; j++) {                                              
            for (var i=0; i<=col; i++) {
                $('#container').append('<div class="grid-box"></div>');
            };
            $('#container').append('<div class="next-row"></div>');
        };
        $('.grid-box').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', "red");
        });
    });   
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.grid-box` element not present in `DOM` when event handler called ? Try using event delegation. See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
// delegate `mouseenter` event to `.grid-box` parent element `#container`
$("#container").on("mouseenter", ".grid-box", function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', "red");
});

$('button').click(function() {

    $('#container').empty();                                                    
    var row = prompt("How many rows are desired?");
    var col = prompt("How many columns are desired?");

    for (var j=0; j<=row; j++) {                                              
        for (var i=0; i<=col; i++) {
            $('#container').append('<div class="grid-box"></div>');
        };
        $('#container').append('<div class="next-row"></div>');
    };
});
```

Comment: I have demo here https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/fsqfu0e7/. Though I have not delegated the event how is this working? any idea?

Comment: _"trying to create an Etch-A-Sketch using a grid of boxes created from div elements, but the code handling the highlighting of the boxes (mouseenter method) is not working."_ , _"Though I have not delegated the event how is this working? "_ Same `html` , `js` as described at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314: can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: @user2181397: thanks for the suggestions, but my problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop counts wrongly, check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da3fz5er/)

**HTML**

```
<button>Start</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#container').empty();                                                    
    var row = prompt("How many rows are desired?");
    var col = prompt("How many columns are desired?");

    for (var j=0; j<col; j++) {                                              
        for (var i=0; i<row; i++) {
            $('#container').append('<div class="grid-box">&nbsp;o</div>');
        };
        $('#container').append('<div class="next-row"></div>');
    };
    $('.grid-box').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', "red");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.next-row{
  clear: both;
}
```